Are voltage ratings defined differently for capacitors and light bulbs?
The voltage rating of a capacitor is the maximum operating voltage, while the voltage rating of a light bulb is its normal operating voltage. Are there two different definitions of voltage ratings, or am I misunderstanding something?

For a device which is designed to operate across a wide range of voltages, such as capacitors, resistors, inductors, transistors, many ICs etc., I would expect the stated voltage rating to refer to the maximum it can reliably function with. For some, like ICs, you will often see a minimum value quoted too.
If the device is intended for use with a fixed voltage source such as mains-powered lamps, laptop chargers and TVs or low-voltage DC devices such as relay coils (which require their coils to be powered using a specific voltage) and car stereos, the quoted voltage will be the "normal" operating voltage, as you call it. Whatever voltage you apply will have to be close to that, and shouldn't deviate "too far". How far is acceptable is also usually quoted, either on the device itself or in its documentation. You might see something like "12V±0.5V", or "11.5V to 12.5V" or similar.
I often see laptop and USB chargers with labels like "220-240VAC". That tells me that I shouldn't deviate outside those bounds. If it just said "230VAC", I'd have to use common sense, and assume that since the mains supply is never exactly 230V, they must really mean something like 220V to 240V.
Context is your only guide, when the meaning is ambiguous. The more you deal with electrical devices, the more experience you gain, the easier it becomes to infer the meaning of such terms, because you tend to automatically understand why any other interpretation makes no sense.
It makes absolutely no sense for a manufacturer to state categorically that their product is designed to work at exactly 230VAC, and no other value, because there's not a single power company that can guarantee the voltage coming out of your home's sockets is exactly that. There has to be some flexibility, even if the label on the device doesn't imply it.
It's pretty well known that older 74 series TTL integrated circuits operate at 5V. You might work really hard to make a supply of exactly 5V, so that you doesn't fry the ICs, but if you read the documentation carefully, you would find that actually they will work reliably with any voltage from 4.75V to 5.25V, and save yourself a lot of bother. Still, if you ask an engineer "what voltage does a standard 74 series TTL IC require?", the answer will be 5V, period. A pedantic one like me might say 5V±0.25V, but the short answer is just 5V.

You have to read (and often decode) the fine print. Power ratings for resistors usually assume reasonable operating conditions while for transistors they assume heroic cooling measures.

The rating for a light bulb will be in terms of RMS voltage i.e. 230 volts however, 230 volts RMS will cyclically peak at 1.4142 times higher (normally). A capacitor rating is usually regarded as a peak voltage rather than RMS. However, there are variations on this dependent on capacitor dielectric so, this answer is a generalism but, works for most situations.
Remember also that a light bulb performs a user function i.e. it produces light. It consumes power to produce that light and this means that there is an RMS voltage association (rather than a peak voltage association).

Thanks. That is a good point. However, for a light bulb, we always try to operate it at the rated voltage, whereas for a capacitor, we want to operate it below the rated voltage. So, would they be different?

@hana a capacitor (generally) doesn't have a rated voltage because it is meaningless whereas a bulb has a light output/power rating by which customers can decide to pick higher or lower powers to suit what they need and, that power is dictated by the RMS voltage. What you call the rated voltage for a capacitor is a limit voltage that you should try and stay within to ensure decent lifetime for the component. It's not a rated value.

@Andyaka at least murata states a "rated voltage" for their cap which is defined as "The rated voltage is defined as the maximum voltage which may be applied continuously to the capacitor" - e.g., see GRM022R71C102KE14L datasheet.

No they are not really defined that differently, if you compare that they are completely different components or loads.
You typically use the lamp at it's rated voltage for rated output. You can and will use the lamp at other voltages too, because e.g. mains voltage is allowed to be higher or lower within some rated tolerance (say 5%), and in cars, the volage is higher when alternator is charging the battery.
If you deviate too much from the rated voltage, the lamp life will go down quickly with overvoltage as it runs much hotter than expected and if used with undervoltage, the lamp may also degrade if they are run much colder than expected.
That only applies to tungsten filament lamps. Modern LED lamps have a power supply that drives the LEDs at constant power regardless of input voltage fluctuations.
Now a capacitor works and can be used at any voltage, up to the maximum safe operating voltage rating. In fact in many cases you actually don't want to use capacitors at near the maximum rated voltage for many reasons (safety, ESR, capacitance, heating), and these reasons are different for different types of capacitors, and in which case you select the capacitor type along with the ratings depending on for what purpose you need the capacitor.

For ceramic capacitors, the capacitance can drop with increasing DC bias voltage. E.g. the following is from the Murata Ceramic Capacitors FAQ : Does the capacitance change when a DC voltage is applied to ceramic capacitors? Are there any points to be aware of regarding changes in the capacitance?:

Please note that among ceramic capacitors, the capacitance, especially of capacitors classified as high dielectric constant (B/X5R, R/X7R characteristic), may differ from the nominal value when a DC voltage is applied.
For example, as shown in the chart, the larger the DC voltage applied to the high dielectric constant capacitors, the more effective capacitance is reduced.
In the following chart, the horizontal axis shows the DC voltage applied to the capacitor (V), and the vertical axis shows the capacitance change ratio against the initial value.*
Thus, the characteristic of change in capacitance according to the applied voltage is called "DC (direct current) bias characteristic."


While the question doesn't mention the application of the capacitor, if say using a ceramic capacitor for a power supply de-coupling application then the change in capacitance with the DC bias voltage might affect the selection of the "nominal value" of capacitance to get the required capacitance value at the DC bias voltage of the circuit.
As pointed out by a comment from @user1937198, the DC bias current curve depends upon the dielectric material used, which should hopefully be specified in the datasheet.

It's important to note the dc bias voltage curve is not directly related to the max voltage rating of the capacitor. Its related to the dialetric material, and capacitors with different capacitance values within the same family with the same rating may have different curves due to different dielectrics being used to get different capacitance in the same package.
